# typed character is getting covered by extension when I am typing

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, user-interface

I have serchable drop down list in my react component. I have not used any css for it. but it is covering last character when I am typing.when I checked it is extension vault. I am not able to remove it. how can I remove it in my code?. I mean is there any css which can overrite it? like `S` is covered.I have marked in `red` if I type next character it will be covered

[image]

When I clicked on that character and inspected below `css` is coming but after lot of permutation I could not resolve it.
[image]

this is my code for `Select` component
import Select from "react-select";

```
<Select
    id="sponsor" 
    name="sponsor"
    className="form-control"
    placeholder="Select the sponsor"
    options={result.map((sponsor:Sponsor)=>
          ({ label: sponsor.name, value: sponsor.id })
    

  )}
  onChange={ (sponsorId:any,e:any)=>{
      setFieldValue("sponsor",sponsorId.value)
      result.map((sponsor:Sponsor)=>{
       if(sponsorId.value===sponsor.id){
       setFieldValue("address",sponsor.address);
       setFieldValue("address2",sponsor.address2);
       setFieldValue("zipCode",sponsor.zipCode);
       setFieldValue("city",sponsor.city);
       setFieldValue("sponsor",sponsor.name)
       }
      })
   }}
/>
```

Comment: Do you have any browser extensions that could be appending it?

Comment: as such there is no. is there anything I can override if customer has that extension?

Comment: there is extension and I am not able to remove due to organization plicy. anything I can do to remove it on page?

Comment: Try this css: 

input[type=text] { background: none !important }

Comment: actually its not working. I am using scss file. can you please guide me bit more?